# Hibernate 5.4.15.final missing SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties() method

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 5.4.15.fianl version to connect to DB2 database. When creating the SessionFactory I am getting the following error:

```
   *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.<init>(QueryPlanCache.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
```

Using Configuration class object to configure properties,

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();

config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.sslConnection", "true");`enter code here`
String fmtHomeDir = FMTEnvironment.getFMT_HOME_DIR();
String certPath= fmtHomeDir + File.separator + "security" +File.separator +"TGenClientTrust2.jks";
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.sslTrustStoreLocation",certPath);
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.sslTrustStorePassword", ****);

config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect");
//optional to fix cmd issue
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
config.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

// end-cmd issue
config.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, String.valueOf(false));

// login property
config.setProperty("log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL", "info");
config.setProperty("log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type", "trace");

// adding entity annotations
config.addClass(Categories.class);
config.addClass(Functions.class);
```

I tried all the possible combination found on the web to get sessionfactory object,
1. From above Configuration object:

```
    Configuration config = legacyBootStraping();
    sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
```

2. BootStrapRegistryBuilder and Metada

```
     BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder bootstrapRegistryBuilder = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder();
        bootstrapRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader( ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() );
        BootstrapServiceRegistry bootstrapRegistry = bootstrapRegistryBuilder.build();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder( 
        bootstrapRegistry );
        standardRegistryBuilder.applySettings(getSettings());
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry =standardRegistryBuilder.build();
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry );
        sources = getConfigMetadata(sources);
        MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = sources.getMetadataBuilder();
        Metadata metadata = metadataBuilder.build() 
        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

3. Configuration with StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

```
     Configuration config = getLegacyBootStrapConfig(); // get the above configuration 
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder stdServBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = stdServBuilder.applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Each call directly/indirectly reached to the hibernate class :
 SessionFactoryImpl constructor  line:259 --> this.queryPlanCache = new QueryPlanCache( this );
QueryPlanCache --> calling SessionFactoryImplementor class method getProperties()

getProperties() method is not part of this class and getting the exception : org/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Early response is really appreciated. I have tried most of posts mentioned here like clean the previous compiled code, try to remove some persistence class version etc. but nothing workout for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. In my working env. couple of more jar files were loaded by the class loader. There as a conflict in the load order. I found fix to load hibernate lib first followed by the rest.

Comment: I have version 5.6.14 and getting the same issue. Also, I don't have a maven but only Ant. So, it's not possible to manage dependency with maven. could you please let me know how you resolved this? What are the libraries you added. I am migrating for hibernate 3 to hibernate 5.